# New app creation using Mobile Blazor binding errors

Tags: c#, android, code-generation, blazor

I'm currently learning how to use blazor and create a mobile version of an application with it using Mobile blazor bindings. I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/walkthroughs/build-first-app but when I try to test the project in the android emulator (without touching anything, The emulator won't start the app. I tried to apply these modifications to solve the problem: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/xamarin/MobileBlazorBindings/49/577226053 but I obtain these errors :

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to generate Java type for class: Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\DEVELOPPEMENT\_Accecia\Stagiaires\Blazor\MobileBlazorBindings\MobileBlazorBindingsApp\MobileBlazorBindingsApp.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache cache) MobileBlazorBindingsApp.Android
```

Thank you in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path length is limited. Try to shorten the path length.
Read more [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/521034/failed-to-create-javatypeinfo.html#)